# Webpack generated file error : "t.replace is not a function"

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm working on some sample Angular 2 app with Webpack that generates some js and css files. I already ran my app as a web application on JBoss AS 7.1 successfully, but when I tried to use it as a portlet application on WebSphere Portal 7, the following error occurred:

[image]

My guess is that `replace` function is not called on a string variable (as it should), but I have no idea, why is this happening (only on portal).

Can anyone help me understand the stacktrace above?

Here's my Webpack configuration if it helps:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry : {
        'polyfills' : './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor' : './src/vendor.ts',
        'app' : './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve : {
        extensions : [ '', '.js', '.ts' ]
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/.AngularPortlet/dist/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

    module : {
        loaders : [ {
            test : /\.ts$/,
            loader : 'ts'
        }, {
            test : /\.html$/,
            loader : 'html'
        }, {
            test : /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader : 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        }, {
            test : /\.css$/,
            exclude : helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
        }, {
            test : /\.css$/,
            include : helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader : 'raw'
        } ]
    },

    plugins : [ new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name : [ 'app', 'vendor', 'polyfills' ]
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        xhtml : true,
        minify : {
            keepClosingSlash : true
        },
        template : 'src/index.html',
        favicon : 'public/images/favicon.ico',
        filename : 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })  ]

};
```

Configuration for web application is the same except `publicPath` for Webpack output files is slightly different.

xhtml code (I'm just simply including a generated index.html code):

```
<div xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="formMain">
    <ui:include src="../dist/index.html" />
</h:form>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/" />
<title>Angular With Webpack</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/.AngularPortlet/node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/.AngularPortlet/node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link
    href="/.AngularPortlet/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link
    href="/.AngularPortlet/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/.AngularPortlet/dist/favicon.ico" />
<link href="/.AngularPortlet/dist/app.f16840a33ca242ab101a.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/.AngularPortlet/dist/polyfills.f16840a33ca242ab101a.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/.AngularPortlet/dist/vendor.f16840a33ca242ab101a.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/.AngularPortlet/dist/app.f16840a33ca242ab101a.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to run it as a web application on Websphere Application Server or as a Portlet in Websphere Portal Server?

Comment: By the way, the times I've seen these types of errors, it usually turns out to be a clash between javascript libraries in the Theme and portlet.  Verify that none of the js libraries loaded by the theme are also loaded by the portlet app.

Comment: @Carlos I'm running it on JBoss as a web application and on Websphere Portal Server as a portlet. Also, thanks for a suggestion, I'll check if there's any JavaScript clash.

Comment: Can you post the portlet's doview?

Comment: @Carlos I have a JSF portlet and there's no doView method. I can post some html code if it helps.

Comment: Yes if you could post your .xhtml view that might help.

Comment: @Carlos I added my xhtml code. I just included a Webpack generated html code into it. I don't see any potential library clash, do you?

Comment: Various observations and suggestions to troubleshoot.
1. Is the page rendering?  If it is, what do the urls for the resources in the included index.html look like?  The way to include resources in portlets is:  <%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/pathtoresource.js")%>

Comment: 2.  Related to #1, verify that all resources that you are loading are really loading.  URLs in portlets should generate something like /wps/portletappcontext/pathto/resource.js.

3.  Portlets should only contain html tags that would go between the body tags of the page.  So it should not include tags like html, head or body.  I'm guessing you are going to have to modify the index.html to accommodate to this restriction.

Comment: @Carlos Your 3rd suggestion helped a lot! After removing html, head and body tags I managed to load portlet without errors. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.